# Dropdown active status is the issue for parent div in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code

```js
$(function(){

    $("li div.main-section").addClass("active");
    $('li > div > a').on('click',function(event){
        $('li > div').removeClass("active");
        $(this).closest('div').addClass("active");
    });

                    
      $('li > div > .dropdown-arrow').on('click',function(event){
          event.preventDefault()
          $(this).closest('li').find('ul').first().toggle(300);
          
      });
});
```

```css
ul{
list-style:none;
}
.dropdown-main li  .dropdown-main {
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-main .active{
    background-color: rgba(0,201,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-main" >
  <li class="dropdown" >
    <div class="main-section">
      <button class="dropdown-arrow">+</button>
      <a href="" ><span>Main Menu</span></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-main">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <div>
          <button class="dropdown-arrow">+</button>
          <a href="" ><span>Sub Menu</span></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-main">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <div >
              <button class="dropdown-arrow">+</button>
              <a href="" ><span>Child Menu</span></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="dropdown-main">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <div >
                  <button class="dropdown-arrow">+</button>
                  <a href="" ><span>Grand Child Menu</span></a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Description------------------

Case:1 By default active status for main menu color (blue).

Case:2 On clicking the '+' button the drop down need to be expand and collapse.

Case:3 On clicking the string (like main menu, sub menu, child menu..Garnd child menu) need to changes the active state.

Case:4 If child (Child Menu) string is active when the parent(Sub Menu) '+' button clicked clear the collapse(Child Menu) and remove the active class state and add to active class color to parent(Sub Menu) div.

Case:5 If child (Child Menu) string is not active when the parent(Sub Menu) '+' button clicked clear the collapse(Child Menu) and keep the active class state and parent(Main Menu) div.

[image]

Help welcome

Comment: Do you have some specific issues? At the moment this is a list of requirements, not a question about logic that you have issues with.

Comment: Please see my code and I done half of it but not able to changes the active state

Comment: If you have any suggest please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the submenus you do not click on `li > div > a` but you click on `li > div > button`. Change that and your code should work.

Plus, some of your explanations ( cases ) are not really clear, so if this code doesn't solve your problem please let me know in the comments below.

Regarding the rest of your code ( jQ + html ) i'm a bit confused.

Why have the same classes on the sub-menu's ( at least add a specific class to each one ) ?

Why use `span` inside the `a` if you do not separate anything ? why not just leave the `<a>` tag ?

Do not use empty `href` but instead use a `/` href and `preventDefault()`.

But also, why use `a` tag in the first place if you do not want to use it as an `a` tag ? :) use just `span` or something else.

```js
$(function() {

  $("li div.main-section").addClass("active");
  $('li > div > a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    $('li > div').removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest('div').addClass("active");
  });


  $('li > div > .dropdown-arrow').on('click', function(event) {
    const subMenu = $(this).closest('li').find('ul').first()
   
    if ($(subMenu).is(':visible')) {
      $('li > div').removeClass("active")
      let newActive = $(this).closest('.dropdown-main').prev("div")
      $(newActive).addClass('active')
    }
 $(subMenu).toggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
ul{
list-style:none;
}
.dropdown-main li  .dropdown-main {
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-main .active{
    background-color: rgba(0,201,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-main" >
  <li class="dropdown" >
    <div class="main-section">
      <button class="dropdown-arrow">+</button>
      <a href="" ><span>Main Menu</span></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-main">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <div>
          <button class="dropdown-arrow">+</button>
          <a href="" ><span>Sub Menu</span></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-main">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <div >
              <button class="dropdown-arrow">+</button>
              <a href="" ><span>Child Menu</span></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="dropdown-main">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <div >
                  <button class="dropdown-arrow">+</button>
                  <a href="" ><span>Grand Child Menu</span></a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mihai T, This not my required solution. But In my case I need to change background color only when I clicked on string(like main menu...Grand child menu). No need to change the background color when I clicked '+' button.

Comment: so, when you click on `Sub Menu` you just want to have ' blue background ' but not show the `Child Menu` ? To show the `Child Menu` you need to click on the button ? and what else

Comment: By default  active background need to be remains in first parent div. And change the active background when I click on next div

Comment: And If a child div is having active background  state, when I clicked on parent '+' button, then clear the sub menu and active state and add to the active background to the clicked parent div .

Comment: Hmm. Hope i understood correctly. Check now the edited answer

Comment: I real thanks for you help, but I'm not good in explain the issue. The active background will change only when I clicked the string(content) value. It will not change on clicking the "+" button.

Comment: Check update. Now the active class is added on the div when you click on the text. Then when you click on button, the sub menu appears. If you click the button again, the submenu closes, and the active menu changes from the previous active, to the parent of that previous active.

Comment: @vj.madamala7 is this what you wanted ?

Comment: Thanks for not giving up on this. I made this with your code help  https://codepen.io/vjmadamala7/pen/LXLOOd

Answer (score 0):

I've made some modifications to your code

```js
$('#cssmenu li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').show();
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('href');
  var element = $(this).parent('li');
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
    element.removeClass('open');
    element.find('li').removeClass('open');
    element.find('ul').slideUp(200);
  } else {
    element.addClass('open');
    element.children('ul').slideDown(200);
    element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp(200);
    element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
    element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
    element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(200);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 220px;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > ul {
  display: block;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #00c9ff;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #d8f3f0;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 26px;
  top: 19px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  top: 23px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub.open > a:after,
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub.open > a:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 14px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
  background: #0d97bb;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  top: 16px;
  right: 26px;
  background: #ddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  top: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> Menus</a>
        <ul>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Child menu 1</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Grand menu 1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Grand menu 2</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Grand menu 3</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Grand menu 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Child menu 2</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Grand menu 1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Grand menu 2</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Grand menu 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a>
              <ul>
                 <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Child menu 1</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Grand menu 1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Grand menu 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Child menu 2</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Grand menu 1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Grand menu 2</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Grand menu 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Settings</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```